# How can I pull in files by extension from latest state of remote repo on top of old local repo?

Tags: git, github

I have reset my repo to old commit, now how can I pull in latest .properties files on top of it, from a remote repo, not my origin.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that are using the `master` branch, which locally you have reset to some earlier commit.  You can achieve what you want by first fetching the latest `master` from the repo.  Then checkout your single properties file from that latest remote `master` branch.

```
# update your origin/master with the latest from the remote
git fetch origin

# switch to the master branch (or another branch)
git checkout master

# checkout the properties file from the latest remote master
git checkout origin/master -- path/to/file.properties
```

Comment: Nice. Though I'd like to get all files by extension from any path. Its difficult for me to really analyze the paths.

Comment: You might need a script to do this.  This feels a bit like a hack.  Maybe you can elaborate on why you need to be working in an in-between Git state like this.

Comment: A lot of functionalities have changed so for checking a particular flow how it worked old, I need old state and thats the reason I did a reset on older commit. Now the *.properties files may have updated URLs etc to other services. Hence, I need a latest layer of these files on top of the older commit. And hence the requirement.

Comment: Well one obvious solution would be a bash script which finds the files, and then issues a `git checkout` for each one from the remote master.  Maybe someone else can give you a better answer.